# Add/Remove bytes from end of file on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, filesize, truncate

So, I've looked around, but couldn't find a way to remove bytes from the end of a file without rewriting the entire file. I found that [a `truncate` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392444/how-to-remove-x-bytes-from-the-end-of-a-large-file-without-reading-the-whole-fil) works for linux, but didn't find anything for windows. Now, obviously, to expand a file, I can just pad the end with null bytes, but for reducing a file's size, is it literally necessary to rewrite the whole file on windows? or **is there a function, maybe in `windows.h`, that allows me, like `truncate` on linux, to reassign a file's size?**

**EDIT:**  I did just find the function `_chdir(int,long)`, and I'm reading on how to use it.

**EDIT:**  And, why exactly did `fstream` leave out this vital function?

**EDIT:**  Ok, so it appears that `_chdir()` will not work (I forgot to mention this, btw), because the function **must support files larger than 4 GB** - i.e., I'm using 64bit file pointers. I thought that would be inherent, but after reading the arguments to `chsize`, the length is not `size_t`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://superuser.com/questions/299329/resize-a-file-in-command-prompt

Comment: Not really - I wouldn't necessarily use the *system* commandline function just to run a process that's already in c++ as a function (i.e. SetEndOfFile).

Comment: Link against Apache Portable Runtime and use apr_file_trunc http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.4/group__apr__file__io.html#gac067fe5f208c927cf6d213197b9335a8

Comment: Sry, no thanks - I'm not exactly up to appending a library and switching all my code over to apache file functions in order to gain the ability of one function.

Comment: @AUTO: Sorry misread your question, realized after edit window but left the link as it may help others.

Comment: @AUTO No need to "switch all code over" its just one function, up to you though whether you want to use a cross-platform library or maintain #ifdefs or whatnot for cross platform functionality

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to truncate a file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873454/how-to-truncate-a-file-in-c)

Comment: there's `_chsize_s` that supports files largr than 4GB

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You truncate a file by calling [`SetFilePointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541.aspx) or [`SetFilePointerEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365542.aspx) to the desired location followed by [`SetEndOfFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365531.aspx). The following shows how a `truncate` function can be implemented:

```
bool truncate( HANDLE hFile, LARGE_INTEGER NewSize ) {
    LARGE_INTEGER Size = { 0 };
    if ( GetFileSizeEx( hFile, &Size ) ) {
        LARGE_INTEGER Distance = { 0 };
        // Negative values move the pointer backward in the file
        Distance.QuadPart = NewSize.QuadPart - Size.QuadPart;
        return ( SetFilePointerEx( hFile, Distance, NULL, FILE_END ) &&
                 SetEndOfFile( hFile ) );
    }
    return false;
}

// Helper function taking a file name instead of a HANDLE
bool truncate( const std::wstring& PathName, LARGE_INTEGER NewSize ) {
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW( PathName.c_str(), GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ,
                                NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
                                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL );
    if ( hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
        return false;
    }
    bool Success = truncate( hFile, NewSize );
    CloseHandle( hFile );
    return Success;
}
```

---

*EDIT: Shorter Version*
The `truncate` function can be shortened to the following:

```
bool truncate( HANDLE hFile, LARGE_INTEGER NewSize ) {
    return ( SetFilePointerEx( hFile, NewSize, NULL, FILE_BEGIN ) &&
             SetEndOfFile( hFile ) );
}
```

If you would rather want to pass the amount of bytes by which to shrink the file, the following implementation can be used:

```
bool truncate( HANDLE hFile, LARGE_INTEGER ShrinkBy ) {
    ShrinkBy.QuadPart = -ShrinkBy.QuadPart;
    return ( SetFilePointerEx( hFile, ShrinkBy, NULL, FILE_END ) &&
             SetEndOfFile( hFile ) );
}
```

---

To grow a file, open the file using [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) with a `dwDesiredAccess` that contains [`FILE_APPEND_DATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364399.aspx). Using `SetFilePointer` again to set the file pointer to the end of file you can then write new data calling [`WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747.aspx). For an example, see [Appending One File to Another File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363778.aspx).

---

*EDIT: Growing a file without writing to it*

If you don't care about the file contents beyond the original file size you can apply the same sequence as shown for truncating a file to extend it:

```
bool SetFileSize( HANDLE hFile, LARGE_INTEGER NewSize ) {
    return ( SetFilePointerEx( hFile, NewSize, NULL, FILE_BEGIN ) &&
             SetEndOfFile( hFile ) );
}
```

This is documented behavior for [`SetEndOfFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365531.aspx):

> The **SetEndOfFile** function can be used to truncate or extend a file. If the file is extended, the contents of the file between the old end of the file and the new end of the file are not defined.

Comment: I like this answer, but I'd like to get it to work before I officially accept it. It might be some time though; I'm still researching exactly how to do it. I don't use windows functions often.

Comment: Thanks! For growing a file, I just used the ofstream::write to dump a zeroed buffer at the end (multiple times if necessary). I'm pretty sure it's about the same thing..

Comment: @AUTO In fact, you can call `truncate` to **grow** a file as well, if you pass a `NewSize` parameter that is larger than the current size. This likely gives you better performance than calling `ofstream::write()`.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want the [SetEndOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365531.aspx) function.

EDIT: This should work with files larger than 4GB. Use the [SetFilePointerEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365542.aspx) function for that.

Comment: Both `SetFilePointer` and `SetFilePointerEx` support files larger than 4GB.

Comment: @IInspectable: I know, but the first seems to be a pain to use.

Answer (score 0):

To remove bytes from end of file on Windows:

```
FSUTIL file seteof <filename> <new size>
```

To add (null)bytes to end of (existing)file:

```
FSUTIL file seteof <filename> <new size>
```

No need to copy/"rewrite the whole file on windows"