# fstream delete N bytes from the end of a binary file

Tags: c++, fstream

Is it possible to delete N bytes from the end of a binary file in C++ using `fstream` (or something similar)? I don´t want to read the whole file, cut it and write it again, but since it´s from the end of a file it seems like it shouldn't be such a problem.

Comment: [How to remove X bytes from the end of a large file without reading the whole file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7392444/995714)

Comment: [How to truncate a file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/873454/995714)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not aware of a generic C++ (platform independent) way to do this without writing a new file. However, on POSIX systems (Linux, etc.) you can use the [`ftruncate()` function](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ftruncate). On Windows, you can use [`SetEndOfFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This also means you'll need to open the file using the native functions instead of `fstream` since you need the native descriptor/handle for those functions.

EDIT: If you are able to use the [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) library, it has a [`resize_file()` function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#resize_file) in its Filesystem library which would do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

Now in C++17 you can use [resize_file](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/resize_file) from [filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)

Live on [Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69635716233b1343)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use Qt, `QFile` also provides two `resize()` methods that allow to truncate a file.